# Preventing a multiplication expression evaluating in Sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, latex, sympy

I am generating an expression with two fractions, and want to pretty print as a whole expression with LaTeX, to then put on a worksheet.

E.g. in the form:

```
(5/7) * (3/4).
```

However, when I do the following:

```
fract1 = sympy.sympify(Fraction(5,7))
fract2 = sympy.sympify(Fraction(3,4))
expression = sympy.Mul(fract1,fract2,evaluate=False)
```

It returns

```
5*3/(7*4)
```

Clearly it is combining the fraction but not actually evaluating, but I want to be able to produce it in a format suitable as a question for a maths worksheet.

Comment: is the end goal just printing or you want the expression to be evaluated later on?

Comment: Yes, I want to both print it and then evaluate later on.

Comment: Examples are being added to SymPy's tutorial: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12232

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next SymPy version will have `UnevaluatedExpr`:

```
In [4]: uexpr = UnevaluatedExpr(S.One*5/7)*UnevaluatedExpr(S.One*3/4)

In [7]: uexpr
Out[7]: 5/7⋅3/4
```

To release and evaluate it, just use `.doit()`:

```
In [8]: uexpr.doit()
Out[8]: 
15
──
28
```

LaTeX output looks like:

```
In [10]: print(latex(uexpr))
\frac{5}{7} \frac{3}{4}
```

This feature is available since SymPy 1.1. See the [documentation to find out more](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#prevent-expression-evaluation).

Comment: thank you! Was this pre-planned or in response to the question ?

Comment: The functionality had been added a few months ago to the master development branch. Documentation in the SymPy tutorial was added in response to this question (it was missing).

Answer (score 2):

Very hackish way to do it (just for your case of two fractions):

```
def print_fractions(expr):
    print("({}) * ({})".format(*expr.args))
```

Works like this:

```
In:  expr = sympy.Mul(sympy.S("5/7"), sympy.S("3/4"), evaluate=False)
In:  expr
Out: 5*3/(7*4)
In:  print_fractions(expr)
Out: (5/7) * (3/4)
```

You can check with `srepr` that the fractions are actually not combined in `expr`, it's just the way sympy decides to print it:

```
In:  sympy.srepr(expr)
Out: 'Mul(Rational(5, 7), Rational(3, 4))'
```

Another approach is to extend `sympy.Mul` overriding `__str__` method:

```
class MyMul(sympy.Mul):
    def __str__(self):
        return "({}) * ({})".format(*self.args)
```

Then you'll have:

```
In:  expr = MyMul(sympy.S("5/7"), sympy.S("3/4"), evaluate=False)
In:  print(expr)
Out: (5/7) * (3/4)
```

**Eidt: how to make `latex()` to work**

Hackish approach again, but:

```
class MyMul(Mul):
    def _latex(self, _):
        return r"\left({} \cdot {}\right)".format(*map(latex, self.args))
```

Now:

```
In:  a = S("5/7")
In:  b = S("3/4")
In:  c = MyMul(a, b, evaluate=False)
In:  print(latex(c))
Out: \left(\frac{5}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{4}\right)
```

Of course, you can change what exactly you're outputting in the definition of `_latex` above.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. It works, however the problem arises once latex is involved, as sympy.latex would not work on that string created.

Comment: @benjo456 Nothing prevents you from hacking `_latex` method for the class as well. I'll add it to the answer now.