# Is there a non-hack way to print continued fractions in SymPy with integers without evaluation?

Tags: sympy

I would like to see continued fractions with integers displayed in that form with `SymPy`, but I cannot seem to make `SymPy` comply. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486283/preventing-a-multiplication-expression-evaluating-in-sympy) Stack Overflow question and answer very useful (see farther below), but cannot reach my target goal here:

[image: example of continued explicit fraction notation]

This is the *continued fraction expansion* of $\frac{13}{5}$. A common notation for this expansion is to give only the boxed terms as does `SymPy` below, i.e., $[2,1,1,2]$ from the `SymPy` `continued_fraction_iterator`:

```
Rat_13_5 = list(continued_fraction_iterator(Rational(13, 5)))
print( Rat_13_5 )
```

```
Rat_13_5 = list(continued_fraction_iterator(Rational(13, 5)))
( Rat_13_5 )
print( Rat_13_5 )
```

With output `[2, 1, 1, 2]`.

Pg 37 of the Sympy manual release 1.5 Dec 9, 2019 gives a code snippet to print such an expanded fraction list:

```
def list_to_frac(l):
    expr = Integer(0)
    for i in reversed(l[1:]):
        expr += i
        expr = 1/expr
    return l[0] + expr
```

If you invoke `list_to_frac` with the `Rat_13_5` continued fraction expansion list, `SymPy` takes off and evaluates it:

```
print( list_to_frac( Rat_13_5 ) )
```

with output `13/5`

If you use a list of symbols instead, then `list_to_frac` prints the desired continued fraction, e.g.,

```
n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9 = symbols('n1:10')
cont_frac_list = [n2, n1, n1, n2]
contfrac12201015 = list_to_frac( [n2,n1,n1,n2] )
contfrac122010154
```

Which produces the desired (I am working in a JupyterLab environment so am actually obtaining typset LaTeX output throughout):

```
n2 + 1/(n1 + 1/(n1 + 1/n2))
```

I rewrote `list_to_frac` to use the `UnevaluatedExpr` facility presented by [Francesco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5190654/francesco-bonazzi) in the StackOverflow question I cited earlier:

```
def list_to_frac_noEval(l):
    expr = Integer(0)
    for i in reversed(l[1:]):
        expr = UnevaluatedExpr(expr + i)
        expr = UnevaluatedExpr( 1/expr )
    return l[0] + expr
```

Invoking `list_to_frac_noEval` on the $\frac{13}{5}$ expansion list:

```
list_to_frac_noEval( [2,1,1,2] )
```

I obtain output

```
2 + (1 + (1 + 2**(-1))**(-1))**(-1)
```

Some folks use that notation (so I wanted to share `list_to_frac_noEval` in any case, that being superior to ending up with an evaluated single rational if you want to see the continued fraction), for example Roger Penrose in section $\unicode{x00A7}3.2$ of *The Road to Reality* (2004), but I still find it annoying that I cannot obtain the explicit continued fraction format when using integers instead of symbols.

I experimented with substituting in integers for symbols with `evaluate=False`, using both the `subs` method and the `Subs` function, looked at various combinations of `sympify` and `srepr` and `parse_expr` with `evaluate=False`, , but cannot persuade `SymPy 1.4` to print the explicit fraction form that I obtain with `list_to_frac` operating on symbol arguments. Is there a way to accomplish this short of modifying `SymPy` code or special casing a particular set of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the expression explicitly passing `evaluate=False` to each part of the expression tree:

```
def list_to_frac(l):
    expr = Integer(0)
    for i in reversed(l[1:]):
        expr = Add(i, expr, evaluate=False)
        expr = Pow(expr, -1, evaluate=False)
    return Add(l[0], expr, evaluate=False)
```

That gives:

```
In [2]: nums = list(continued_fraction_iterator(Rational(13, 5)))

In [3]: nums
Out[3]: [2, 1, 1, 2]

In [4]: list_to_frac(nums)
Out[4]: 
      1          
───────────── + 2
    1            
───────── + 1    
  1              
───── + 1        
0 + 2
```

It looks like it's the wrong way around but that's just the way the printing works with default settings:

```
In [5]: init_printing(order='old')

In [6]: list_to_frac(nums)
Out[6]: 
          1      
2 + ─────────────
            1    
    1 + ─────────
              1  
        1 + ─────
            0 + 2
```

You can trigger evaluation with `doit`:

```
In [7]: _.doit()
Out[7]: 13/5
```

Comment: Nice solution. My SymPy 1.4 in Jupyter Lab is not changing the display from Hebrew to normal with the init_printing(order='old'), but that is minor. Also, my version if not printing 0+2 but rather the proper 1/2 fraction, so I won't complain. It is interesting to see the operations tree in action here. Thanks.

Comment: The output I showed above is with sympy master which is close to the recently released sympy 1.7.1

Comment: Good to know (re the difference in behavior of init_printing is due to change in the new release, i.e., an improvement). I will "stand pat" (re draw no more cards and go with the hand I have).